# Recognizing Patterns In Images Neural Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I have a set of images. To be more precise there are 4 main patterns that can be found in that images. They are quite different to each other.
But there is a quite a big variance in the each pattern itself.
I can distinguish them without a problem but I need to find a way to automate it.
All images are black and white images 255x255.
One very distinguishable pattern is basically 4 scare like group of pixels in upper left section of the image?

What type of the ANN would be more suited for that kind of problem.

I am using Neuroph.

Answer (score 0):

A multi(4) class NN classifier with one hidden layer should work.
I would configure 10 to 100 nodes in the hidden layer and use cross entropy as the cost function.